# Replace spaces in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, replace, formatting

I want to replace my_string

```
my_string = '[[4.6, 4.3, 4.3], [8.75, 5.6, 6.6], [4.6, 4.3, 4.3]]'
```

such that it gives result like this

```
my_string = '4.6x4.3x4.3 8.75x5.6x6.6 4.6x4.3x4.3'
```

I have tried this but this fills up the empty space with "x" too

```
mystring = mystring.replace("[","").replace("]","").replace(", ","x")
```

Is there a better pythonic way to do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use regex to extract the contents of sublists:

```
import re

s = '[[4.6, 4.3, 4.3], [8.75, 5.6, 6.6], [4.6, 4.3, 4.3]]'

' '.join(i.replace(', ', 'x') for i in re.findall(r'\[([^\[\]]+)\]', s))
# 4.6x4.3x4.3 8.75x5.6x6.6 4.6x4.3x4.3
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this :

```
import ast
my_string = '[[4.6, 4.3, 4.3], [8.75, 5.6, 6.6], [4.6, 4.3, 4.3]]'
mystring = " ".join(["x".join([str(k) for k in i]) for i in ast.literal_eval(my_string)])
# mystring = '4.6x4.3x4.3 8.75x5.6x6.6 4.6x4.3x4.3'
```

Comment: some better naming can go a long way here. How about `sublist` instead of `i` and `num` instead of `k`? Other than that, +1

Answer (score 1):

split it with `],` and do what you're already doing:

```
my_string = '[[4.6, 4.3, 4.3], [8.75, 5.6, 6.6], [4.6, 4.3, 4.3]]'

for e in my_string.split("],"):
    print(e.replace("[","").replace("]","").replace(", ","x"), end = "")
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
4.6x4.3x4.3 8.75x5.6x6.6 4.6x4.3x4.3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
import ast
str = '[[4.6, 4.3, 4.3], [8.75, 5.6, 6.6], [4.6, 4.3, 4.3]]'
my_list = ast.literal_eval(str)
result = ' '.join(['x'.join("{}".format(item) for item in sub_list) for sub_list in my_list])
print(result)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use eval directly without import ast.

```
my_string = '[[4.6, 4.3, 4.3], [8.75, 5.6, 6.6], [4.6, 4.3, 4.3]]'
my_list = eval(my_string)
result = ' '.join(['x'.join("{}".format(item) for item in sub_list) for sub_list in my_list])
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
'4.6x4.3x4.3 8.75x5.6x6.6 4.6x4.3x4.3'
```